# "dyld: Library not loaded" error with CocoaPods and watchOS 2

Tags: ios, cocoapods, watchos-2, github-mantle

I'm getting the following error when trying to run Mantle via CocoaPods on watchOS 2:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/Mantle.framework/Mantle
Referenced from: [...]
Reason: image not found
```

Mantle is working just fine in my main app - only the watchOS 2 app seems to be affected.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Look in to your pod file, maybe you have platform or target dependency there? Or paste your code here

Comment: Same problem on running UITests on a Project using RestKit pods. Did you find a solution?

Comment: Sadly no, after over a day trying to figure out a solution, I had to strip Mantle out of my project completely and redo everything associated with it. Huge headache.